# Another way of doing integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, polylogarithm

What's your option for calculating this integral? No full solution is necessary, it's optional as usual.

Calculate 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{2 \zeta (3)\log ^3(1-x) \text{Li}_2(1-x) }{x}-\frac{2 \zeta (3) \log ^2(1-x) \text{Li}_3(1-x)}{x}+\frac{ \log (x) \log ^5(1-x)\text{Li}_2(1-x)}{x}+\frac{\log ^4(1-x)(\text{Li}_2(1-x){})^2 }{x}-\frac{ \log (x) \log ^4(1-x)\text{Li}_3(1-x)}{x}-\frac{2 \log ^3(1-x)\text{Li}_2(1-x) \text{Li}_3(1-x) }{x}+\frac{\log ^2(1-x)(\text{Li}_3(1-x){})^2 }{x} \textrm{d} x.$$

Did you meet it before? Some references, papers?

**EDIT I:** I'm going to remove the first 2 terms since I see the way to go there, and all reduces to

$$\int_0^1 \frac{ \log (x) \log ^5(1-x)\text{Li}_2(1-x)}{x}+\frac{\log ^4(1-x)(\text{Li}_2(1-x){})^2 }{x}-\frac{ \log (x) \log ^4(1-x)\text{Li}_3(1-x)}{x}-\frac{2 \log ^3(1-x)\text{Li}_2(1-x) \text{Li}_3(1-x) }{x}+\frac{\log ^2(1-x)(\text{Li}_3(1-x){})^2 }{x} \textrm{d} x$$
which looks way simpler.

**EDIT II:** Thanks, I'm done with the question (I successfully finalized the calculations).

**EDIT III**: *Supplementary question* - Where is Cleo? I miss Cleo.

Comment: Knowing where you found it might help others answer your question.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli it's some stuff usually arising in my work. My intuition tells it has a very nice closed form.

Comment: Arising in your work as an artist?  Do tell.  And please explain your intuition, since most integrals do not have nice closed form.

Comment: For starters, factor out the denominator and write $\dfrac{dx}x$ only once at the end. Then let $t=1-x,$ since the latter occurs $11$ times, whereas *x* appears just thrice.

Comment: @GEdgar to me an artist is, amongst other things, someone that doesn't have limits in his/her work (let the creativity fully manifests). The intuition is very precious but hard to explain.

Comment: lol .. didn't see the third *supplementary question* :P

Answer (score 6):

Adding up the integrands so that all terms are over the common denominator $x$, we find that the resultant numerator factors in a very helpful way. As is, spotting a convenient way to group the terms isn't exactly easy, but if you're familiar with the Nielsen generalized polylogarithm you'll find that it tidies things up quite nicely.

In particular, note the following identity:

$$S_{1,2}{\left(1-x\right)}=-\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}+\ln{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x\right)}+\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1-x\right)}+\zeta{(3)}.$$

Them,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}\ln^{5}{\left(1-x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-x\right)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}\ln^{4}{\left(1-x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(1-x\right)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{4}{\left(1-x\right)}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-x\right)}\right]^{2}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1-x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(1-x\right)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-x\right)}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(1-x\right)}\right]^{2}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\small{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-x\right)}\left[\ln{\left(1-x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-x\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(1-x\right)}\right]\left[\ln{\left(1-x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-x\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(1-x\right)}+\ln{\left(x\right)}\ln^{2}{\left(1-x\right)}\right]}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
&=\small{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-x\right)}\left[S_{1,2}{\left(x\right)}-\zeta{(3)}-\frac12\ln{\left(x\right)}\ln^{2}{\left(1-x\right)}\right]\left[S_{1,2}{\left(x\right)}-\zeta{(3)}+\frac12\ln{\left(x\right)}\ln^{2}{\left(1-x\right)}\right]}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-x\right)}\left[\left(S_{1,2}{\left(x\right)}-\zeta{(3)}\right)^{2}-\frac14\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}\ln^{4}{\left(1-x\right)}\right]}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-x\right)}\left[S_{1,2}{\left(x\right)}-\zeta{(3)}\right]^{2}}{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~-\frac{6!}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}\ln^{6}{\left(1-x\right)}}{2\left(6!\right)x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\zeta{(3)}}\left[S_{1,2}{\left(x\right)}-\zeta{(3)}\right]^{2}\,\mathrm{d}S_{1,2}{\left(x\right)}-\frac{6!}{2}\,S_{3,6}{(1)}\\
&=\frac23\,\zeta{(3)}-360\,S_{3,6}{(1)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Going this route is likely orders of magnitude quicker than trying to integrate each of initial terms individually.

Comment: Interesting way (+1)